# Python - relative path "with open(..) - function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new in python.

I would like to ask, how I can use a relative path in this function: 
with `open('path?', 'r') as file`:

I want to have a relative path to my desktop.

This function is from the module:

```
import xlsxwriter
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried using the relative path as the first argument to `open`?

Comment: Just the same way you would use a non-relative path.

Comment: There was no actually identified issue here; of the two provided answers, one is guessing at an issue without explaining it, and the other (the accepted one) is completely wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
open('/relative//path//to//file', 'r')
```

If its windows dont forget put // otherwise python will not interpret it properly

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code.

```
import os
dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dir, '/relative/path/to/file/you/foryourdir')
```

instead of the path you can correct path for the desktop.

Comment: `dir()` is a built-in function in python, so do not shadow it with your `dir` variable